# Fisher Forecasting For EUCLID Experiment Help

Tags: cosmology, experimental-physics, astrophysics, computational-physics, software

I'm trying to recreate the results of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08016

[image]

to obtain the constraints for the matter density and hubble constant h.

However every time I try to create there results my Fisher Matrix has elements of order of 10^14 which is far to high. I suspect this is happening because the Vsurvey I'm calculating is so large. I have no idea how they were able to there. Results. I'll attach my Mathematica code for the F_11 element of the Fisher Matrix. I don't know if I'm am misunderstanding a formula, if its a mathematica error or if there is some missing step.

> ```
>            Parallelize[
>            Total[Table[(NIntegrate[(E^(0)) ((D[
>          Log[Pobs, 
>           H]] /. {Da -> (300000/(1 + z)*
>             NIntegrate[
>              1/(68.8` \[Sqrt](0.7015117571500769` + 
>                 0.2984` (1 + Z)^3 + 
>                 0.00008824284992310034` (1 + Z)^4)), {Z, 0, z}]), 
>          H -> 68.8` \[Sqrt](0.7015117571500769` + 
>               0.2984` (1 + z)^3 + 
>               0.00008824284992310034` (1 + 
>                 z)^4)})^2)*(Veff /. {Da -> (300000/(1 + z)*
>           NIntegrate[
>            1/(68.8` \[Sqrt](0.7015117571500769` + 
>                 0.2984` (1 + Z)^3 + 
>                 0.00008824284992310034` (1 + Z)^4)), {Z, 0, z}]), 
>        H -> 68.8` \[Sqrt](0.7015117571500769` + 
>             0.2984` (1 + z)^3 + 
>             0.00008824284992310034` (1 + z)^4)})*
>     k^2/(8*Pi^2), {u, -1, 1}, {k, 0, 
>     f[z]}]) ((D[(100 hh Sqrt[
>         1 - 0.000041769223554`/(hh)^2 - MM + MM (1 + z)^3 + (
>          0.000041769223554` (1 + z)^4)/(hh)^2]), 
>       MM] /. {MM -> .2984, hh -> .688})^2) + 
> 2*(D[(300000/(1 + z)*
>       NIntegrate[
>        1/(100 hh Sqrt[
>           1 - 0.000041769223554`/(hh)^2 - MM + MM (1 + Z)^3 + (
>            0.000041769223554` (1 + Z)^4)/(hh)^2]), {Z, 0, z}]), 
>     MM] /. {MM -> .2984, 
>     hh -> .688})*(D[(100 hh Sqrt[
>       1 - 0.000041769223554`/(hh)^2 - MM + MM (1 + z)^3 + (
>        0.000041769223554` (1 + z)^4)/(hh)^2]), 
>     MM] /. {MM -> .2984, hh -> .688})*
>  NIntegrate[(E^(0)) (D[
>       Log[Pobs, 
>        H]] /. {H -> (68.8` Sqrt[
>          0.7015117571500769` + 0.2984` (1 + z)^3 + 
>           0.00008824284992310034` (1 + z)^4]), 
>       Da -> (300000/(1 + z)*
>          NIntegrate[
>           1/(68.8` \[Sqrt](0.7015117571500769` + 
>                 0.2984` (1 + Z)^3 + 
>                 0.00008824284992310034` (1 + Z)^4)), {Z, 0, 
>            z}])}) (D[
>       Log[Pobs, 
>        Da]] /. {Da -> (300000/(1 + z)*
>          NIntegrate[
>           1/(68.8` \[Sqrt](0.7015117571500769` + 
>                 0.2984` (1 + Z)^3 + 
>                 0.00008824284992310034` (1 + Z)^4)), {Z, 0, z}]), 
>       H -> (68.8` Sqrt[
>          0.7015117571500769` + 0.2984` (1 + z)^3 + 
>           0.00008824284992310034` (1 + 
>              z)^4])})*(Veff /. {H -> (68.8` Sqrt[
>          0.7015117571500769` + 0.2984` (1 + z)^3 + 
>           0.00008824284992310034` (1 + z)^4]), 
>       Da -> (300000/(1 + z)*
>          NIntegrate[
>           1/(68.8` \[Sqrt](0.7015117571500769` + 
>                 0.2984` (1 + Z)^3 + 
>                 0.00008824284992310034` (1 + Z)^4)), {Z, 0, 
>            z}])})*k^2/(8*Pi^2), {u, -1, 1}, {k, 0, 
>    f[z]}] + ((D[(300000/(1 + z)*
>         NIntegrate[
>          1/(100 hh Sqrt[
>             1 - 0.000041769223554`/(hh)^2 - MM + MM (1 + Z)^3 + (
>              0.000041769223554` (1 + Z)^4)/(hh)^2]), {Z, 0, z}]), 
>       MM] /. {MM -> .2984, 
>       hh -> .688})^2)*(NIntegrate[(E^(0)) ((D[
>          Log[Pobs, 
>           Da]] /. {H -> (68.8` Sqrt[
>             0.7015117571500769` + 0.2984` (1 + z)^3 + 
>              0.00008824284992310034` (1 + z)^4]), 
>          Da -> (300000/(1 + z)*
>             NIntegrate[
>              1/(68.8` \[Sqrt](0.7015117571500769` + 
>                 0.2984` (1 + Z)^3 + 
>                 0.00008824284992310034` (1 + Z)^4)), {Z, 0, 
>               z}])})^2)*(Veff /. {Da -> (300000/(1 + z)*
>           NIntegrate[
>            1/(68.8` \[Sqrt](0.7015117571500769` + 
>                 0.2984` (1 + Z)^3 + 
>                 0.00008824284992310034` (1 + Z)^4)), {Z, 0, z}]), 
>        H -> 68.8` \[Sqrt](0.7015117571500769` + 
>             0.2984` (1 + z)^3 + 
>             0.00008824284992310034` (1 + z)^4)})*
>     k^2/(8*Pi^2), {u, -1, 1}, {k, 0, f[z]}]), {z, .7, 2.1, .1}]]]
> ```

This code is supposed to calculate F_11 and

```
     Pmatter = 
     E^(-k^2*u^2*
 rr^2)*(((8 Pi^2*(300000)^4*.002*2.45*10^-9)/(25*((100*h)^4)*
    M^2))* 

(0.02257`/(h^2*M)*Tb + ((M - 0.02257)/M)*Tc)^2)*((Gz/
  Go)^2)*(k/.002)^.96




        Pobs = ((Dref)^2*H)/(Da^2*Href)*Pg;



       Veff = (((1.2*Pg)/(1.2*Pg + 1))^2)*Vsurvey;




      Pg = (1 + 
  z) (1 + (0.4840378144001318` k^2)/((k^2 + u^2) Sqrt[1 + z]))^2*
     Pmatter
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

If anyone has had similar issues, can offer any help or has done this calculation before I will greatly appreciate your help.

Oh and my Vsurvey is Vsurvey = 5.98795694781456`*^11(MPC)^3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about debugging a code and not physics.

Comment: It is about physics. I have no idea if my code is even right. This is a question more about how to construct a Fisher Matrix to forecast the EUCLID experiment. If course there is code, why would anyone do this by hand.

Comment: *I don't know if I'm am misunderstanding a formula, if its a mathematica error or if there is some missing step.* strongly suggests you are asking us to debug your equations. That's not what we do here (see the [tag:computational-physics] tag). It's possible that [so] or [scicomp.se] might accept this question, as phrased.

Comment: But would there be a physicists on those pages who know how to construct  Fisher Matrix using the Power Spectrum of the upcoming EUCLID survey?

Comment: I am not deleting the question, I'm voting to [close it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). And the lack of [MathJax'd equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) don't matter to me here, [topicality is the issue](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5603/): I don't think this is on-topic here because you're not asking about physics, you're asking about how to implement a calculation.